# Getting a keyerror after trying to add value from SQL query to an int

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

```
# Query for remaining cash
cash = db.execute('SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = :id', id=user_ID)
cash = float(cash[0][0])

netValue = cash + totalStock
```

I am getting KeyError: 0 with no explanation when I run the web page. I have already tried the following:

```
cash = float(cash[0])
```

```
cash = float(cash)
```

```
next(iter(cash.values()))
```

What is the structure of what was returned from the SQL query?

Comment: It's showing a KeyError because it's trying to access an element that doesn't exist or is not in that list or dictionary. Check the type of `cash` or check the `keys` for `cash` if it's a dictionary type.

Comment: And what does your `next(iter(cash.values()))` tell you?

Comment: @alaniwi It tells me that cash does not have 'values'

Comment: Does it have `items`? (Look at `dir(cash)` to find out.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`KeyError: 0` occurs when you try to access a key that isn't in the dictionary, i.e.`cash.values`

This means that `values` is not a valid key for your `cash` dictionary.

I would suggest running `print(cash)` so you can check what is inside your dictionary, and alter your code based on it.

Comment: I am using flask to run my code in HTML. Any way I can check the type or debug in my python script?